# RuntimeException on app load only in production release

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am having an issue with an app I am creating. Basically the app will crash the first time you try to open it and then it will be alright after that. The confusing part is it only happens when you download the app from Google Play. If I load the app on my phone straight from Android Studio I don't get any errors.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3290)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1715)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3285)
```

After researching this issue I have found people say to clear the cache of the device. This fixed the issue...but that just wipes the app and it works fine from then on. The initial install still crashes. This has happened on multiple devices yet I cannot reproduce it while debugging. My only thought is that I have this code in the onCreate() right after I call setContentView().

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationListener.class);
startService(intent);
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

NotificationListener.class extends NotificationListenerService. Everything works great except for the initial launch.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I set the service in the AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Here is a simplified version of my NotificationListenerService:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService
{
    private IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

        // custom code
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        if (SERVICE_INTERFACE.equals(intent.getAction()))
            return super.onBind(intent);
        else return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        public NotificationListener getService()
        {
            return NotificationListener.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ServiceConnection for the Binder:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder)
    {
        NotificationListener.LocalBinder localBinder = (NotificationListener.LocalBinder) iBinder;
        notificationListener = localBinder.getService();
        bound = true;

        // code to call custom function in NotificationListener class
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName)
    {
        notificationListener = null;
        bound = false;
    }
};
```

I know this has to be an issue with the binding of the service because if I remove all of the binding code and just start the service, everything runs as it should. It is only when I add the binding code that I get this error.

Comment: Could you try creating apk file without proguard if you do?

Comment: @KimKevin Does that just involve removing the entry for it in the buildTypes in the app gradle? If so, I removed it and uploaded a beta version of my app and still got the same error on launch.

Comment: yes it is. minifyEnabled sets as false. or because ClassNotFoundException occurred ... did you register NotificationListenerService to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @KimKevin I removed the proguard and set minifyEnabled to false. Yes I put the NotificationListenerService in the manifest as a service.

Comment: It's my mistake. NotificationListener should be set in AndroidManifest.xml. pretty sure you did...

Comment: please add NotificationListener and AndroidManifest codes.

Comment: @KimKevin Please see my edit. I'm curious after looking through the documentation some more if the intent-filter on the service in the manifest could be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing and editing. I think you need to check NotificationListener.class file in build folder (maybe path is build/intermediates/classes/your_package/NotificationListener). please rebuild before looking for it.

Comment: @KimKevin I found it where you said.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't need to start and bind service again. please creating signing apk file after deleting below codes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationListener.class);
startService(intent);
```

[EDIT]

I think it's proguard obfuscation, so please add the following codes to your proguard file.

```
# Base Android exclusions, required for proper function of various components
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: I went ahead and removed the startService() call since it bindService() should handle it. It still crashes though. I want to see if the error changed but I don't get any crashes for the beta for some reason.

Comment: Yeah I still get the same error when I remove the startService().

Comment: I don't have experience dealing with the proguard files so I went ahead and added that to both my proguard-android.txt-2.3.3 file and to my aapt_rules.txt file. It still crashes though.

Comment: Any other ideas on this? Was that proguard-android.txt-2.3.3 file the right file to put those changes you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem happen because of proguard, If you add proguard into your project it'll stop some of functionality like this.

Just try to add your service module in **proguard-rules.pro** file by adding

> -keep class {package-name}.{service-module-name}.** { *; }
>
> For Example : > -keep class com.demo.service.** { *; }

this will add all services permission in proguard.

Comment: Can I just remove proguard if having it causes an issue?

Comment: Every things has there own pros and cons, Proguard has also.it'll provide you good security and many other features too.
So, my opinion is to add this files to proguard-rules.pro file instead of totally removing it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassNotFoundException` here has an empty message. Looking at the `dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader` source code, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` with the name of the indicated class if it can't find it, therefore, you are passing an empty class name somewhere (namely, in the message that is handled by `ActivityThread::handleReceiver`. It would greatly help if you could provide the full stack trace (i.e. the `handleMessage` branch which delegates this `handleReceiver` call).